# 5030 in ls output.?

Tags: users, ls

I am getting the following in the output of `ls` for the home directory of `arcsight` user.

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 5030 tspplatformadmin    4096 2016-01-28 02:51 arcsight
```

What I expected the output to be:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 arcsight tspplatformadmin    4096 2016-01-28 02:51 arcsight
```

I can't understand what `5030` is. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

5030 is the UID (User ID) of the `arcsight` user. It means that this user is not defined in the local `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: I have deleted this user but still its home directory is there and now i want to delete its home directory but even root is getting permission denied. cani have any other solution to delete the home directory.

Comment: Perhaps that homedir is not on the local disk (is a SMB or NFS share) and the local root user hasn't permission over it. Please post the output of `mount`.